# ODOO Pricelist | How to set the base price PUBLIC PRICE to not get modified based on the discount applied.?

Tags: list, odoo, product, price

I'm using the ODOO pricelist for sales.order and invoice. The issue i'm facing is : I create a PRICELIST, and add PRODUCT-X with a rule of NEW PRICE  = BASE PRICE(PUBLIC PRICE) x (23%) where the Product's Sale Price in Warehouse is set to let's say 770  and the discount is 23 percent - The discount gets applied  to 770 the first time = 592.9- then once the product is added for a second time the 770 is no longer used as a base price, but the 592.9 is used and a 23 percent discount is applied and so forth...

So we have non-stable PRODUCT_X Public Price.

Please view the image below to get a clear picture of what goes on, i want the PUBLIC PRICE to not change automatically... If someone could give me advice, or if there's any module out there on the Odoo apps..

**NOTE IN THE IMAGE BELOW: the PRIX PUBLIC field is French for  LIST PRICE
& the REMISE field is DISCOUNT

[image]

[image]

Now at the end we will have a look at the Product's PUBLIC PRICE and it will be 351.53 instead of 770 (we set at the beginning).

[image]

Thanks alot,

Comment: Did you install custom modules? Seems weird that the public price is updated while creating order lines.

Answer (score 1):

## PROBLEM SOLVED

I removed this code in my **sale_order.py**

```
        product_obj = self.pool.get('product.product')
    if 'price_unit' in vals:
        for this in self.browse(cr,uid,ids,context):
            if this.product_id:
                price_unit = vals.get('price_unit',0.0)
                if this.product_id.lst_price != price_unit:
                    product_obj.write(cr,uid,[this.product_id.id],{'lst_price':price_unit})
```

It was making the PUBLIC PRICE updated from the order line for every addition.

Thanks @CZoellner for your valuable help - a reminder that the process wasn't running normally.